# Time continuous white noise

Tags: continuity, noise

I am aware there are similar questions about the subject, but my question is probably much more simple.

I want to know why is the expectation of the second moment of continuous time white-noise equal to the some constant times the delta function, or:

$E[w(t)w(t+\tau)] = Q \delta(\tau)$

I am aware of the difficulties involving the definition of a function that is discontinuous in all points, but I just wish to know why engineers defined it like this.
I appreciate on-line references to the subject. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because the PSD of the white noise process is by definition a constant $Q$. So, by [Wiener-Khinchin theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener-Khintchine_theorem) the auto-correlation function is $$r_{ww}(\tau):=\mathbb{E}\left(w(t)w(t+\tau)\right)=\mathcal{F}^{-1}(Q)=Q\delta(\tau)$$

The motivation for the definition comes from the frequency domain description of random processes. White noise is a pure theoretical model which simply assumes that the spectral power density is same for the noise process in all frequency bands.

A practical example which has a description close to white noise is the Thermal noise in electrical circuits which has a constant power spectral density over a large band of frequencies. [See here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_noise) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

See [this answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/8632/235) (and the link cited therein) on dsp.SE for why *engineers* define white noise the way they do.  On the other hand, as
the lack of answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/134193/15941)
seems to indicate,
there appears to be no mathematical difficulty in defining a continuous-time
white noise as one for which 
$$E[X(t)X(t+\tau)]= \begin{cases}\sigma^2, & \tau = 0,\\
0, & \tau \neq 0.\end{cases}$$
where $\sigma^2$ is the variance of all the random variables comprising the process.

Comment: I like your answer, but I guess what I wanted to know was this Wiener–Khinchin theorem.

Comment: Just be careful and read beyond the Wikipedia page on the Wiener-Khinchin theorem. As that page says, the theorem holds if $E[X(t)X(t+\tau)]$ is finite for all $\tau$, and so applying the theorem to the Dirac delta requires some additional machinery.