# Does A Continuous Time White Noise Process Actually Exist?

Tags: stochastic-processes, independence, noise

I have seen white noise defined as a zero-mean stochastic process with the following autocorrelation function (in this question, for example [Time continuous white noise](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/452145/time-continuous-white-noise)):
\begin{align*}
E[X(t)]E[X(t+\tau)] = \begin{cases} 
          \sigma^2, \tau=0 \\
          0, \tau \neq 0 \\
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

However, my understanding is that there are fundamental difficulties with constructing uncountably many independent non-constant random variables in the first place. The argument put forth in the answer to [Showing that there do not exist uncountably many independent, non-constant random variables on $ ([0,1],\mathcal{B},\lambda) $.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1549807/showing-that-there-do-not-exist-uncountably-many-independent-non-constant-rando) seems to only depend on the orthogonality of the random variables in the collection, and so it seems to suggest that uncountably many uncorrelated non-constant random variables do not exist on $([0,1], \mathbb{B}, \lambda)$.

This leads me to the following questions:

- Is my assumption that the argument in [Showing that there do not exist uncountably many independent, non-constant random variables on $ ([0,1],\mathcal{B},\lambda) $.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1549807/showing-that-there-do-not-exist-uncountably-many-independent-non-constant-rando) applies to both independent and uncorrelated random variables incorrect, and therefore the definition of continuous white noise above works just fine?
- Does the definition of white noise implicitly assume that the random variables are defined on some probability space other than $([0,1], \mathbb{B}, \lambda)$ whereupon uncountably many independent non-constant random variables can exist?